# Is there any way to use a numeric type as an object key?

Tags: javascript, object, types, key, numeric

It seems that when I use a numeric type as a key name in an object, it always gets converted to a string. Is there anyway to actually get it to store as a numeric? The normal typecasting does not seem to work.

Example:

```
var userId = 1;
console.log( typeof userId ); // number
myObject[userId] = 'a value';
console.dir(myObject);
```

Dir Output:

```
{
    '1': 'a value'
}
```

What I **want** is this:

```
{
    1: 'a value'
}
```

Advice?

Comment: Also see this comment - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633362/is-there-any-way-to-use-a-numeric-type-as-an-object-key#comment91311499_3633390

Comment: I tried your example, but I got the result you want. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  **The key will always be converted to a string.** See [Property Accessor docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

> Property names must be strings. This means that non-string objects cannot be used as keys in the object. Any non-string object, including a number, is typecasted into a string via the toString method.

```
> var foo = {}
undefined

> foo[23213] = 'swag'
'swag'

> foo
{ '23213': 'swag' }

> typeof(Object.keys(foo)[0])
'string'
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this considered a flaw in the language, or is it accepted as a good design decision?

Comment: That's rather subjective.  As William noted, for integer keys you can instead use an array.  Most JS engines can use sparse arrays behind the scenes.

Comment: Even in an array, all property names are converted to strings.

Comment: @TimDown, that's very misleading. Array indexes and array properties are not the same thing.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: Not, it isn't. The only difference is that assigning a numeric property to an array affects the array's `length` property.

Comment: @TimDown, nope that's certainly not the only difference. Javascript is not like PHP, which supports associative arrays. Javascript allows only (sparse) numeric array indexes. It also allows array properties/methods to be set/read, but they are NOT ARRAY ELEMEMTS!!!

Comment: That the length property changes when array elements are added/removed, is symptomatic of the difference, not the difference itself.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: I'm not clear on what you're saying. All I'm saying is that the only difference between getting and setting properties when using an Array and a plain Object is that setting a numeric property on an Array can affect the `length` property. There is no other distinction between a property with a numeric and non-numeric name (and as I've previously mentioned, a numeric property name is converted to a string when setting the property anyway).

Comment: @TimDown, and what I'm saying is that you are wrong. "Setting a numeric property on an Array can affect the length property" is an incorrect statement. Javascript Array properties are completely independent of Array elements. What confuses people is that associative syntax, eg `myArray["1"] = foo`, *appears* to be setting a property, whereas it actually sets an array element, but only because "1" is a string representation of an integer, which is complete linguistic nonsense - but that's Javascript.

Comment: Meanwhile, if you were to execute `myArray["myProperty"] = foo`, an Array element would not be created - the *property* `myProperty` would be set on the Array, but independently of the Array elements and the length property would be unaffected. *[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U2rrt/)*. Please trust me. I may only have a rep of a few hundred here on SO, but I've been writing this stuff for close on two decades and Array basics haven't changed in that time.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: Your demo doesn't disprove anything I've said, and even proves that "setting a numeric property on an Array can affect the length property". I suggest reading the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4): array elements are just properties with special behaviour when setting.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: I feel the same. We might have the same understanding and just be arguing about terminology, seeing as we're both so entrenched. It bothers me and I want to know what it is you think I'm wrong about, so if you want to continue then we could do so in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/56797/roamer-1888-tim-down-arrays-discussion).

Comment: @TimDown, too busy with a heap of other stuff. May not emerge for several days. Best wishes.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: "Javascript Array properties are completely independent of Array elements" is an incorrect statement. `myArray["1"] = foo` doesn't just _appear_ to be setting a property, it is in fact setting a property (with a key "1") in every sense of the definition of property. Eg, `myArray.hasOwnProperty("1")` yields `true`.  Semantically, this property can also be considered an "element" by virtue of having a numeric key, but there is nothing further that distinguishes an array "element" from an array property. Read the spec. If you still disagree, kindly cite your source.

Comment: @Hans, this is precisely why nobody in their right mind, yourself included I hope, would attempt either to teach or to learn javascript programming from the Ecmascript specification(s), which are concerned with *implementation* of the language, not it usage. It *is* true that an array's members are properties of an underlying (concrete) object, but they are *members* of the (conceptual) array - not properties. It is an unfortunate shortcoming of the language that some of the underlying implementation is exposed in some of the notations available to programmers.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: I would rather people learned the reality of how the language works (which may well involve some reading of or reference to the spec) than one person's preconceived idea of some (actually non-existent) difference between array and object properties. It sounds like you're projecting ideas from another language onto JavaScript.

Comment: @TimDown Agreed. A nice feature of specs is that they allow people engaged in a technical discussion to sync up on terminology, avoiding time wasted arguing semantics.

Comment: Please be noted that "The keys of an Object are Strings and Symbols; a symbol value may be used as an identifier for object properties" [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)

Answer (score 48):

In an object, no, but I have found [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) extremely useful for this application. Here is where I have used it for numeric keys, a key-based event.

```
onKeydown(e) {
  const { toggleSidebar, next, previous } = this.props;

  const keyMapping = new Map([
    [ 83, toggleSidebar ],  // user presses the s button
    [ 37, next          ],  // user presses the right arrow
    [ 39, previous      ]   // user presses the left arrow
  ]);

  if (keyMapping.has(e.which)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    keyMapping.get(e.which)();
  }
}
```

Comment: The 101 of elegant [Ludumdare](https://ldjam.com/) entries! +1

Answer (score 14):

Appears to be by design in ECMA-262-5:

> The Property Identifier type is used to associate a property name with a Property Descriptor. Values of the Property Identifier type are pairs of the form (name, descriptor), where name is a String and descriptor is a Property Descriptor value.

However, I don't see a definite specification for it in ECMA-262-3.
Regardless, I wouldn't attempt to use non-strings as property names.

Answer (score 8):

you can use, `Map` if you want different datatype as keys

```
const map1 = new Map();

map1.set(1,3)
map1.set('1','string')

// expected output: 3

console.log(map1.get(1)) //output 3;
console.log(map1.get('1')) //output 'string';
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution. Please tell me the environmental setups if this is not working

```
const screens = {
    "768": "large",
    "200": "small"
}

const keys = Object.keys(screens).map(key => parseInt(key))
                                         // OR Number(key)

console.log(keys) // Output [200, 768]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do we need something like this?

```
var userId = 1;var myObject ={};
console.log( typeof userId ); // number
myObject[userId] = 'a value';
console.dir(myObject);
```

Console:
Object

1
:
"a value"

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but you can always convert keys to a numbers

```
const data = { 15: "value", name: "Apple" };

const result = Object.keys(data) // get keys as an array
    .map((item) => {
    return parseInt(item); // convert to integer number
    })
    .filter((item) => !isNaN(item)); // remove non number elements

    console.log(result); //Output: [15]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const a = {
    '1': 'a value'
}
//by using a + before any string value it will convert(parse) that into a number
const b = Object.key(a);
console.log(+b); //parse
console.log(typeof b); //number
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [ECMA-262 Edition 13 (as of 2024)](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-object-type): *A property key value is either an ECMAScript `String` value or a `Symbol` value*'.

So the answer is still NO, at least not natively.

However, it is technically possible to hack it and convert 32-bit integers into 4-char sequences (strings) and use them as keys (note that those strings **might not** be 4-byte long).
This approach might be useful for compression during transmission of large data objects.
Example:

```js
'use strict';

const { log } = console;

const data = [
    { t: 1705432979, s: 124, d:   0, pl: 0 },
    { t: 1705432992, s: 125, d:  17, pl: "004500" },
    { t: 1705433022, s: 124, d:   0, pl: 0 },
    { t: 1705433330, s:  19, d: 657, pl: "deadbeef" },
];
//log("data_orig:", data);

function int2bstr(val) {
    const arr_u32 = new Uint32Array(1);
    arr_u32[0] = val;
    const arr_u8 = new Uint8Array(arr_u32.buffer);
    return String.fromCharCode(...Array.from(arr_u8));
};
function bstr2int(str) {
    if (str.length !== 4) { throw "Invalid data"; };
    const arr_u8 = new Uint8Array(4);
    const arr_u32 = new Uint32Array(arr_u8.buffer);
    for (let i=0;i<4;++i) { arr_u8[i] = str.charCodeAt(i); };
    return arr_u32[0];
};
// Converting 'Array' into 'Object' and using converted value of property 't' as key.
const data_compr = data.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const k = int2bstr(val.t);
    acc[k] = structuredClone(val);
    delete acc[k].t;
    return acc;
}, {});
log("data_compr:", data_compr);
/*
data_compr: {
    // NOTE: each key is now a 4-char string
    "\u0093×¦e":{ s: 124, d:   0, pl: 0 },
    " ×¦e":     { s: 125, d:  17, pl: "004500" },
    "¾×¦e":     { s: 124, d:   0, pl: 0 },
    "òØ¦e":     { s:  19, d: 657, pl: "deadbeef" }
}
*/

const data_decompr = Object.entries(structuredClone(data_compr)).map(([k,val]) => {
    val.t = bstr2int(k);
    return val;
});
log("data_decompr:", data_decompr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Per Mozilla:
[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
let obj1 = { foo: 'bar', x: 42 };
let obj2 = { foo: 'baz', y: 13 };
const merge = ( ...objects ) => ( { ...objects } );

let mergedObj1 = merge (obj1, obj2);
// Object { 0: { foo: 'bar', x: 42 }, 1: { foo: 'baz', y: 13 } }

let mergedObj2 = merge ({}, obj1, obj2);
// Object { 0: {}, 1: { foo: 'bar', x: 42 }, 2: { foo: 'baz', y: 13 } }

console.log(mergedObj1);
console.log(mergedObj2);
```

Just order the items before hand and you should get the result you want.

So for your case:

```js
const merge = (...objects) => ({...objects});

// An object with numeric keys
const values = ["a value", "another value", "and another value"];
        
let merged = merge(...values);

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: this doesn't answer at all the question and how you see those indexes are converted in String type

Comment: Doing a shallow copy of an object just to convert keys to numbers seems like insane overkill

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

````js
arr = {}
function f(a,b,c) {
      arr = arguments
}
f("*","#","_")
console.log(arr)
//returns Object { 0: "*", 1: "#", 2: "_" }```
````

Comment: Writing something like `arr = {}` is like writing `myBool = 'blue'`. It's almost maliciously unreadable when it comes to code maintenance and updates. A `{}` is not an array, it's an object. An array is written `[]` and calling a spade a shovel doesn't change that fact

Answer (score -4):

In JavaScript, numerical strings and numbers are interchangeable, so

```
myObject[1] == myObject['1']
```

If you really want number to be the key for an object, you might want an array (i.e. created with `new Array()` or `[]`).

Comment: Thanks for the response but this is not entirely accurate. A numeric will only return as 'number' from a typeof, and vice versa with a string.

Comment: @william 'numerical strings and numbers are interchangeable' is simply not correct. Numbers are Numbers and Strings are Strings. See `Object.prototype.toString.call(someObject)` The issue is you can't use a Numbers as keys.