# Check if array keys are numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have array with keys that could be either real strings

```
var array = {
    'Blue' : 1,
    'Red'  : 2,
    'Green': 3
}
```

or it could be numbers but sometimes floats considered as strings, I guess because it's not an array but an object:

```
var array = {
    9     : 1,
    '9.5' : 2,
    10    : 3
    '10.5': 4
}
```

This one is not really an array so I need to sort it if explicitly if I want to keep the original order:

```
$.each(Object.keys(array).sort(function(a, b) {
    var anum = parseFloat(a),
        bnum = parseFloat(b);
    return anum - bnum;
}), function(index, value) {
    ……
});
```

if I don't do that, my array is:

```
var array = {
    9     : 1,
    10    : 3,
    '9.5' : 2
    '10.5': 4
}
```

I need to keep it sorted. My solution is working well but I need to check if the keys are numbers or string. If they are string, I don't need to sort the array. Something like:

```
$.each(/*if my array has numbers as keys I sort the array as above, else just loop*/,
function(index, value) {
    ……
});
```

Comment: You can use ```typeof index === "string"```

Comment: You cannot. [Here is the reason and discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633362/is-there-anyway-to-use-a-numeric-type-as-an-object-key)

Comment: Object doesn't necessarly keep order of properties!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir That is exactly why he is sorting the keys before iterating over them.

Comment: Maybe use try catch. You can put the code inside a try block, then parseInt inside. If it is not parseable the catch block will execute. Make sure to put a parameter on the catch statement to hold the error, then you can just ignore it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Really shouldn't call that object 'array', but:

```
if(Object.keys(array).every(key => !isNaN(key)){ //sort }
```