# How can I join two objects in Angular?

Tags: json, angular, object

how to join to object in angular 2?

**object response 1**

```
0:Object
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
```

**object response 2**

```
0:Object
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
```

myComponent component

```
resultdata :any=Array;

 fooddrinks_data_func(Defaultparams){

    return this.CitiesService.getresult(Defaultparams).subscribe(data => {                
         this.resultdata = this.resultdata.join(data.categorylistvalues);

    });  
}
```

I get this error.

> error_handler.js:59 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:      ErrorHandler.handleError @
>   error_handler.js:59       next @ application_ref.js:348       schedulerFn @
>   async.js:93       SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:234
>         SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:183         Subscriber._next @
>   Subscriber.js:125         Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89      Subject.next
>   @ Subject.js:55       EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79
>         NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:333        onHandleError @
>   ng_zone.js:294        webpackJsonp.1416.ZoneDelegate.handleError @
>   zone.js:338       webpackJsonp.1416.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:169
>         ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:420       error_handler.js:60 TypeError:
>   _this.resultdata.join is not a function

the Final result should be like this.

**this.resultdata**

```
0:Object
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
4:Object
5:Object
6:Object
7:Object
```

Comment: Are the both examples objects or Arrays containing Objects?

Comment: @Bernhard both examples objects.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify what exactly you want/expect as a result?

Comment: @alexkucksdorf, I updated in question part

Comment: This data structure is an Array http://stackoverflow.com/a/3633390/1165289. You can verify if you're trying a console.log((response instanceof Array)===true)

Answer (score 20):

I think you are looking for [object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)?

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

```js
var obj1 = { a: 1 };
var obj2 = { b: 2 };

var merged = Object.assign(obj1, obj2);

console.log(merged); // { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

Comment: You answer is outputting `{a: 1, b: 2}`, not `{a: 1}` as you suggest in the comment after the console log

Comment: Just for a matter of completeness, Object.assign takes the first parameter as the target: this means that obj1 and merged will have the same value. For avoiding this kind of situations, it's always a better practice to set the Object.assign first parameter as {} so no object is modified and the returned value of the method will be just stored in a new variable (merged, in the case of @Mike example).

var merged = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);

Comment: @Mike, after update with you code. the output like that. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t20c.png

Comment: It's also worth noting that TypeScript 2.1 supports the experimental [object spread syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread), which is functionally the same as the code that @AndrewReborn suggested. `let merged = { ...obj1, ...obj2 };`

Answer (score 0):

`Object.assign` is not fully supported in all browsers. 
And the snippet shows commands which are used with Arrays. (.join is a member of Array).

Even the `resultdata` was instantiated as an Array...

So here an example how it works if the responses are arrays as well (and those look like arrays)

```
resultdata :any=[];

fooddrinks_data_func(Defaultparams){
  return this.CitiesService.getresult(Defaultparams).subscribe(data => {                
     // And here concat is better choice 
     this.resultdata = this.resultdata.concat(data.categorylistvalues);
  });  
}
```

Comment: I replaced  to resultdata :any={};

Answer (score 0):

@Mike answer works good.

```
var obj1 = { a: 1 };
var obj2 = { b: 2 };

var merged = Object.assign(obj1, obj2);

console.log(merged); // { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

but after Object.assign obj1 also becomes same as merged

```
console.log(obj1);  // { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

You can use lodash to use one liner solution

```
var obj1 = {a :1};
var obj2 = { b: 2};

_.merge(obj1, obj2);
```

Result will be ---->

```
{
 "a": 1,
 "b": 2
}
```

In addition of that you will lose key if your both object have same key name.

Comment: My two json keys are same. It will not merge?

Comment: I post my two json object in question part

Comment: If key on two object are same then it will merge and most latest one will only be there

Comment: how to fix this?. I want to merge two object?

Answer (score 0):

When reading your code two details called me attention:

- result data wasn't typed as Array
- there were no map() after the getResult method call, that I am assuming is a remote call.

So this is my suggestion of code change

```js
resultdata :Array<any> = [];

 fooddrinks_data_func(Defaultparams){

    return this.CitiesService.getresult(Defaultparams)
    .map((response) => response.json())
    .subscribe(data => {                
         this.resultdata = this.resultdata.join(data.categorylistvalues);

    });  
}
```