# Javascript: Print Object attribute type

Tags: javascript, object, typeof

I have code something like below

```js
var obj = {
  11 : "November", 
  };

for ( var prop in obj ) {
  console.debug(typeof prop) ;
};
```

As I am curious, I tried getting `typeof` attribute in a object, but javascript is returning `typeof` its value. In Other words I need `typeof key` but I am getting `typeof value`.

Is there any way ?

Thank you.

Comment: Object keys will always be strings .. Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/3633390/7785337

Comment: `for (key of Object.keys(obj)) { console.log(typeof key) }`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one, I think it's helpful for you.

```
keys = Object.keys(obj);
for(key of keys) {
    console.log(typeof key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following documentation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

The for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object, if you want to access the value, just `console.log(obj[key])`

Try the code below.

```js
var obj = {
  11: "November",
  l2: "December"
};

for(const key in obj) {
  console.log(key)
  console.log(obj[key])
}
// 11
// November
// l2
// December
```

Comment: This answer is just a link. Please try to explain it.