# can't get data from API (number in var)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, numbers, var

I am trying to work with API, but it doesnt work

```
code:`$.getJSON("https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/info/?application_id=92b412a513708b55eda739c9eaa865a7&account_id=508251079", 
        function(wot){
            console.log(wot);
            var nick = wot.data.508251079.nickname;
            $(".nick").append(nick);
        }
        );`
```

I have problem with numbers in var nick: 508251079
In VS code getting error expected ts(1005) and in console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to use a numeric type as an object key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633362/is-there-any-way-to-use-a-numeric-type-as-an-object-key)

Comment: what is `wot.data`? Show the full json returned by the AJAX call

Comment: Try: `wot.data[508251079].nickname`

Comment: I tried to use wot.data[508251079].nick, but it didn't work
https://ctrlv.cz/nIOd

Comment: What about `wot.data['508251079'].nick` ? - spitballing based on @HarunYilmaz comment

Comment: oh, thank you so much <3