# Javascript: Programmatically set numbers as object keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I have the following data generated by an API:

```
{
  "config": {
    1: {"slot1": "SK_DISENGAGE"},
    2: {"slot1": "SK_DISENGAGE"}
  }
}
```

I transformed `config` into this array of objects below, as it's easier to deal with when displaying it via react-hook-form, and because the items in the object are subject to change:

```
{
  "config": [
    {"slot1": "SK_DISENGAGE", element: 1},
    {"slot1": "SK_DISENGAGE", element: 2}
  ]
}
```

[Here's a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-forked-xhzh9?file=/src/index.js) of the code below:

```
function App() {
  const { register, control, handleSubmit, reset, watch } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      config: [
        { slot1: "SK_DISENGAGE", element: 1 },
        { slot1: "SK_DISENGAGE", element: 2 }
      ]
    }
  });
  // Simplified. The data comes from an API, and useForm would be empty until after the async functions are done.

  const { fields } = useFieldArray({ control, name: "config" });

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log("data", data);

  renderCount++;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <h1>Field Array </h1>
        {fields.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={item.id}>
              {`Item:`}
              <input
                name={`config.${item.element}.slot1`}
                defaultValue={`${item.slot1}`} 
                ref={register()}
              />
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

However, I'm having trouble transforming it back, and it ends up like this:

```
{
  "config": [
    null,
    { "slot1": "SK_DISENGAGE" },
    { "slot1": "SK_DISENGAGE" }
  ]
}
```

`config` is now an array of objects, a format the API will not take kindly to. I've tried modifying the `name` field in the `input` tag, adding `"`, `'`, or no quotes to `item.element`, but the results are the same.

I assume the first element is null because nothing is setting the element 0.

How do I programmatically set a number as an object key? Is there a slash or something I should put in so it should be taken as a string?

Comment: This question does not make a whole load of sense, I know you say you've intentionally simplified but perhaps create a [mcve] to demonstrate the actual problem.

Comment: I think all you need is ``${i}``  with backtits no need of `"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633362/is-there-any-way-to-use-a-numeric-type-as-an-object-key

Comment: Please read the referred link, we can't have number as key at-most we can have {'0':{}}

Comment: You can have numbers as keys in an object but they become stringified. This doesn't seem like an [mcve]--it's difficult to tell what's going on with the code because vars don't exist and it's broken up by English.

Comment: @BhaskerYadav, tried that,`"`, `'`, and none. Same issue, it's defaulting to an array.

Comment: @AbishekKumar, yes, as string. How do I do that? Cause it's defaulting to an array.

Comment: @zack_falcon you do that in `skillConfig` object, but since `config` is an array that won't work on `config`. you can simply use `skillConfig[i] = 'lorel'` where `i` is number in for loop

Comment: @ggorlen I've edited the question with a code sandbox. Hit the submit query button to see the results.

Comment: @Jamiec apologies, i was in a hurry. I've added a code sandbox.

Comment: I've edited the question. Hopefully this is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` method to achieve your desired output. The syntax of array reduce `array.reduce(function(total, currentValue, currentIndex, arr), initialValue)`.

```js
const data = {
  config: [
    { slot1: 'SK_DISENGAGE', element: 1 },
    { slot1: 'SK_DISENGAGE', element: 2 },
  ],
};

const ret = {
  config: data.config.reduce((prev, c) => {
    const p = prev;
    p[c.element] = { slot1: c.slot1 };
    return p;
  }, {}),
};
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change your field mapping to this:

```
{fields.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <li key={item.id}>
          {`Item:`}
          <input
            name={item.element}
            defaultValue={`${item.slot1}`} // make sure to set up defaultValue
            ref={register()}
          />
        </li>
      );
    })}
```

And your `onSubmit` to this:

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {

    var newData = Object.entries(data).reduce( (acc, [key,value]) => {
      acc[key] = {slot1:value};
      return acc;
    },{});
    console.log("data", newData);
}
```

The result is pretty close to your original input.... does that work for you?

Fork of your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-forked-olcn3

Answer (score 0):

Append an `array` field to the original object

```
{
  "config": {
    1: {"slot1": "SK_DISENGAGE"},
    2: {"slot1": "SK_DISENGAGE"}
  },
  "config-arr": [
    {"slot1": "SK_DISENGAGE", element: 1},
    {"slot1": "SK_DISENGAGE", element: 2}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the result I want, although this appears to be born out of misunderstanding due to the way I worded my question. I've added a code sandbox to my question. Please have a look if you have the time. Thanks.