# why does Object.keys(array) return the indexes as a string, and keys(array) returns them as numbers?

Tags: javascript

for example:

```
greetings = ['hey','hi','hello']

Object.keys(greetings) // ["0", "1", "2"]
```

BUT

```
keys(greetings) // [0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: What is `keys()`?

Comment: @VLAZ it seems to be doing the same thing, i tried it on the console...  just a function that gives u keys in an object.

Comment: Keys will always be a string. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3633390/13464279)

Comment: @jayykaa we prefer to not go by "seems like" but something more actionable. I can give you the reference for `Object.keys` but not for `keys`. If it's non-standard, we probably shouldn't be guessing what it does.

Comment: totally understood, trying to learn here. :)

Comment: Question I have is why would you want to use Object.keys on an array in the first place

Comment: @epascarello im learning javascript.  one of the things i was doing was converting an array into an object.  and also converting back.  just playing around...but on the console..so seems i need to note differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying the [command line API's keys](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#keys), which isn't actually part of standard JavaScript. It's something Chromium-based browsers inject in DevTools.

As for why it returns different results, not sure. On the other hand, in JavaScript, indexing with a number is identical to indexing with the string version of that number, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: On FF `keys(["a", "b", "c"])` returns `[ "0", "1", "2" ]`

Comment: i dont know enough about this, so if u get votes ill market it as the answer! thanks

Comment: For me it returns a number array. Since it isn't actually part of any JS specification, it actually doesn't matter how it behaves. Regular JavaScript (in `<script>` tags etc) shouldn't be able to even access that function.