# How to Iterate dictionary in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am learning react with typescript. I have one dictionary of the department in which employees data of department is stored in the form of an array.

```
type Department = {
    Emp_Id: number,
    Name: string,
    Age: number
}
    
let dict: {[DepartmentNo: number]: Department[] } = {};
    
dict[0] = [   {Emp_Id: 1, Name:"Test", Age: 23},
            {Emp_Id: 2, Name:"Test", Age: 23},
            {Emp_Id: 3, Name:"Test", Age: 23}
        ];

dict[1] = [  {Emp_Id: 1, Name:"Test 2", Age: 23},
           {Emp_Id: 2, Name:"Test 3", Age: 23},
           {Emp_Id: 3, Name:"Test 4", Age: 23}
        ];

dict[2] = [  {Emp_Id: 1, Name:"Test 2", Age: 23},
           {Emp_Id: 2, Name:"Test 3", Age: 23}
     ];
```

I created a function that will return me an unordered list.

```
const printDepartment = () => {
     // getting error in map argument: department
    Object.entries(dict).map((department: Department) => {
        let count = 0;
     // here also saying condition will always return true
      if(dict[count] != 2){
          return (<ul>
              <li>{department.Emp_Id}</li>
              <li>{department.Name}</li>
          </ul>)
      }
    })
}
```

in my return I am simply calling this function:

```
<div>
      {
          printDepartment()
      }
  </div>
```

Comment: You've forgotten a `return` as in `return Object.entries(dict).....`

Comment: Also `dict[count] != 2` will indeed always be true because it's never 2 - its an array of `Department` objects

Comment: Im a beginner in React and typescript, this question helped me to map a dictionary to elements, thanx for that 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of keys on your `dict` will always be `string`. If you change that, the types in the `Array.map` element will be correctly inferred as `[string, Department[]]`.

```
type Department = {
  Emp_Id: number;
  Name: string;
  Age: number;
};

let dict: { [DepartmentNo: string]: Department[] } = {};

dict[0] = [
  { Emp_Id: 1, Name: "Test", Age: 23 },
  { Emp_Id: 2, Name: "Test", Age: 23 },
  { Emp_Id: 3, Name: "Test", Age: 23 },
];

dict[1] = [
  { Emp_Id: 1, Name: "Test 2", Age: 23 },
  { Emp_Id: 2, Name: "Test 3", Age: 23 },
  { Emp_Id: 3, Name: "Test 4", Age: 23 },
];

dict[2] = [
  { Emp_Id: 1, Name: "Test 2", Age: 23 },
  { Emp_Id: 2, Name: "Test 3", Age: 23 },
];

const printDepartment = () => {
  Object.entries(dict).map((entry) => { // [string, Department[]] 
    console.log({ key: entry[0], value: entry[1] });
  });
};

printDepartment();
```

[demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhYEMBOwC2EB2woF4oG8AoKKAUVTAH0BJAEwC4oMBXVAIwiQG5ioA5BOkYBnYEgCWGAOY8SAQSkRGLdpx4BfHoQA2EbLXEBjYI3xQA2nEQp0WPgHsRYyVIC6jK8jSZg511HVcAk1CQgNjcwAGfzxzXjNyKjpGAEYAGn5BJSgAIgAVCFEcjIVsgCYAZgC0%20LIKGgYoMoyBIVyCopLFRkrq2sSGxgqWrMZ8wuBiqFKeqvUa1y1w3xSYi3765Kh0zLbx0Sapmaa5mpIEzcbm3ez97Aqj7pO%2087qkxuGbsY7sABZH8qnQiLULLcxlNZxV4DLY7Vq3H6HLqAl4EN6DJojPaIh7I2Z9EGEQz2DAHMASLCeGw%20IIACgAlLgAHwEXgkADybAAVhBjAA6HwSQq05b0vmoBBgWm08wAawgIAyADcENpmBBXIycCyiCQ9XriaT7Lo%20dp7FJafh5YqoCq1RB1PS2QEnepQuTJMAqd4sAygA)

Comment: I defined the key type as ```number```. secondly, my code is also working if I simply ```console.log(department[1])```

Comment: The problem is occuring when I am putting type in map argument like ```department: Department``` and then return a list

Comment: Because you are putting the incorrect type.

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: Object keys are always a string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633362/is-there-any-way-to-use-a-numeric-type-as-an-object-key