# how to get rid of unicode u'string' prefix in Python

Tags: python, string, unicode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suppress the u'prefix indicating unicode' in python strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761361/suppress-the-uprefix-indicating-unicode-in-python-strings)

I assume this is an easy question, I even haven't found an answer on the Web.

I have a string that is unicode encoded and when I print it to the console the string looks like

`u'mystring`'

but I want to get the string itself without 'u' prefix, like

```
'mystring'
```

The question is how to do it?

thanks in advance, guys.

UPDATE:

I use the following code:

```
    req = urllib2.Request(link)
    req.add_header('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0')
    result = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    print result.url
```