# How to make Python 2.x Unicode strings not print as u'string'?

Tags: python, unicode

I'm currently testing a webservice that returns large amounts of JSON data in the form of dictionaries.  The keys and values for those dictionaries are all unicode strings, and thus they print like

```
{u'key1':u'value', u'key2':u'value2'}
```

when printed to the screen in the interactive interpreter.

Now imagine that this is a 3-level deep, 40-element dictionary.  All those *u* characters clutter up the display, making it hard to figure out, at a glance, what the real data actually is.  Even when using *pprint*.

Is there any way to tell the interpreter that I don't care about the difference between normal strings and unicode strings?  I don't need or want the *u*.

The only thing I've found that might have helped was the PYTHONIOENCODING environment variable.  Unfortunately, setting it to 'ascii' or 'latin-1' doesn't make those *u*'s go away.

I'm using Python 2.6, and I use either the regular python interpreter, or iPython.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761361/suppress-the-uprefix-indicating-unicode-in-python-strings

Answer (score 19, accepted):

if it's json you want, just print [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps({u'key1':u'value', u'key2':u'value2'}, indent=4)
{
    "key2": "value2", 
    "key1": "value"
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, that could work.  Once I get back to the office I'll try that out.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Ok, after trying this out, it's perfect!  It's basically Santiago's idea from the other answer, with json.dumps() being the "function to print the dictionary".

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create your own function to print the dictionary? Python's default format is OK for fast, easy debugging, but absolutely inapproapiate for a 3-level deep, 40-element dictionary.

Comment: Hmm, that could work, but it'd be more effort than this problem is really worth.  I was hoping for something like a command-line switch to the interpreter.  I'm already using pprint, which does all the formatting work to make these deep dictionaries somewhat readable, and I'd rather not re-invent the wheel.

Comment: well, you could wrap your strings and override their `repr` method.