# Unicode Prefix on Numbers - Python

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to create a list where I need to input numbers as strings in one list and I am trying to do it with a while loop.

```
while input_list[-1] != "":
    input_list.append(raw_input())
```

However when numbers are entered they are returned as u'X', X being the number entered. I cannot perfrom mathematical calculations on these numbers.

I would usually use str() or int() but I cant generalise in this case.

Is there a cleaner way to remove the u' ' prefix than simpley using if statements?

Comment: `raw_input()` returns *strings*, not unicode values. Yet `u'123'` is a unicode value, did you perhaps replace `raw_input()` with your own function?

Comment: this looks useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761361/suppress-the-uprefix-indicating-unicode-in-python-strings

Comment: Why can you not use `int`? `int(u'123')` returns `123`.

Comment: That said, `int()` works equally well on a unicode string. `int(u'123')` still returns the integer value `123`.

Comment: There are also strings in the list that I want to input. using int() would cause an error

Comment: Then catch the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "u'' prefix" is trying to indicate the type of the value. You have strings here, not numbers. If you want to do math, you need to convert your strings to numbers. If they happen to enter a string that can't be converted to a number, you should tell the user what happened

```
user_typed = raw_input()
try:
    user_number = float(user_typed)
except ValueError:
    print "Couldn't convert this to a number, please try again: %r" % user_typed
```

See also: [LBYL](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl) and [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)

Comment: if user_typed.isdigit == True: int(user_typed) #would be faster, I was counting on a fast solution, doesn't look like it exists.

Comment: @deadfire19: It's not faster in the common case of the user typing a number, since you've scanned the string twice where I've done just once. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I was curious, so I did some profiling on this topic. I found the try/except pattern is only faster if 98% of the input is numbers. http://paste.pound-python.org/show/qFTG4yTJdVSA3TVnQWkr/

Comment: We're talking about a situation where a user is typing in numbers. Profiling the difference between the two is irrelevant.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: From the OP "There are also strings in the list that I want to input."  Please troll less.

Comment: Yes, but in a situation where a user is typing in floats and strings (taking many seconds), I don't think a choice between isdigit() or try/except should be based on profiling something that takes milleseconds either way. Nobody will ever notice the speed difference.