# What is u in front of Mongo Output in Python

Tags: python, utf-8

I am seeing this mongo output after upserting:

`{'updatedExisting': False, u'nModified': 0, u'ok': 1, u'upserted': ObjectId('54c2281ccb163887ec7b9218'), u'n': 1}`

How to get rid of the `u`s. What exactly do they mean?

Comment: unicode identifier I believe: http://www.diveintopython.net/xml_processing/unicode.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761361/suppress-the-uprefix-indicating-unicode-in-python-strings

Comment: Why do you *want* to get rid of them? Depending on what you're doing, you may be able to ignore them completely.