# Django JSONField is adding extra characters u, why?

Tags: python, django

I'm using JSONField [here](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield) for example:

```
sets = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
```

However, when my app (Native not Python) writes to the API Django stores with extra character i.e. `"` becomes `u'`, Why is this and how do I stop it?

Example returned data...

> "sets": "{u'position': {u'y': u'-121-07', etc...

Comment: That is a unicode `u`

Comment: Read more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l

Comment: So ``"`` becomes ``u'`` but this additional character  is given me issues parsing within my app. Are you saying that this shouldn't be an issue and the problem maybe with my native app?

Comment: You should show what this problem is and how you are doing the parsing. The point is that the output you are getting is the *deserialized* value, which is a Python dict and *not* JSON.

Comment: I see that makes sense. So I could just convert it into a JSON object. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `u` is added by Python 2.x as JSONField is using `unicode` strings.

They do no harm. However, if you don't want to see this, you might try Python 3.x since strings are `u` by default there.

See also [Suppress the u'prefix indicating unicode' in python strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761361/suppress-the-uprefix-indicating-unicode-in-python-strings).