# What is the difference between u' ' prefix and unicode() in python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

What is the difference between `u''` prefix and `unicode()`?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print u'上午'  # this works
print unicode('上午', errors='ignore') # this works but print out nothing
print unicode('上午') # error
```

For the third `print`, the error shows: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0

If I have a text file containing non-ascii characters, such as "上午", how to read it and print it out correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761361/suppress-the-uprefix-indicating-unicode-in-python-strings

Comment: The question you've added in your edit is sort of nonsense. What is the encoding of your `"\x97"` byte? Whatever your answer is, use that as the arguement to `unicode` (or `str.decode`) rather than `"utf-8"`. As Joel Spolsky wrote in [the post linked by Martijn Pieters](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html): "**It does not make sense to have a string without knowing what encoding it uses.**"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- `u'..'` is a string literal, and decodes the characters according to the source encoding declaration.
- `unicode()` is a function that converts another type to a `unicode` object, you've given it a *byte string literal*. It'll decode a byte string according to the default ASCII codec.

So you created a byte string object using a different type of literal notation, then tried to convert it to a `unicode()` object, which fails because the default codec for `str` -> `unicode` conversions is ASCII.

The two are quite different beasts. If you want to use the latter, you need to give it an explicit codec:

```
print unicode('上午', 'utf8')
```

The two are related in the same way that using `0xFF` and `int('0xFF', 0)` are related; the former defines an integer of value 255 using hex notation, the latter uses the `int()` function to extract an integer from a string.

An alternative method would be to use the [`str.decode()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode):

```
print '上午'.decode('utf8')
```

Don't be tempted to use an error handler (such as `ignore'` or `'replace'`) unless you know what you are doing. `'ignore'` especially can mask underlying issues with having picked the wrong codec, for example.

You may want to read up on Python and Unicode:

- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: Thank you. It works. But, I tried reading a text file containing non-ascii characters, such as "上午". For each line of the file, I do unicode(line, 'utf8'), it shows the same error as said in the question description.

Comment: @DehengYe: perhaps your file uses a *different codec*? And don't use `unicode()` to decode every line. You can use `import io`, then `io.open(filename, encoding='utf8')` (or another codec) to have Python decode the file contents for you as you read.

Comment: I encounter new problems. Would you be able to see my new edits? Thank you. @MartijnPieters

Comment: @DehengYe: please don't ask new questions in your current post; use new posts for that. You cannot convert that byte because it is *not UTF-8*. You have a different codec there, you'll have to figure out what data you do have. Don't try to decode it as UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

When a `str` is not prefixed by `u''` in `Python 2.7.x`, what the interpreter sees is a byte string, without an explicit encoding.

If you do not tell the interpreter what to do with those bytes when executing `unicode()`, it will (as you saw) default to trying to `decode` the bytes it sees via the [ascii](http://www.asciicodes.us/) encoding scheme.

It does so as a preliminary step in trying to turn the plain bytes of the `str` into a `unicode` object.

Using `ascii` to `decode` means: try to interpret each byte of the `str` using a hard-coded mapping, a number between `0` and `127`.

The error you encountered was like a `dict` `KeyError`: the interpreter encountered a byte for which the `ascii` encoding scheme does not have a specified mapping.

Since the interpreter doesn't know what to do with the byte, it throws an error.

You can change that preliminary step by telling the interpreter to `decode` the bytes using another set of encoding/decoding mappings instead, one that goes beyond ascii, such as `UTF-8`, as elaborated in other answers.

If the interpreter finds a mapping in the chosen scheme for each byte (or bytes) in the `str`, it will decode successfully, and the interpreter will use the resulting mappings to produce a `unicode` object.

A Python `unicode` object is a series of Unicode [code points](http://unicode.org/glossary/#code_point). There are 1,112,064 valid code points in the Unicode [code space](http://unicode.org/charts/).

And if the scheme you choose for decoding is the one with which your text (or code points) were encoded, then the output when printing should be identical to the original text.

Can also consider trying `Python 3`. The relevant difference is explained in the first comment below.

Comment: Python 3 doesn't default *strings* to utf-8 - rather, a `str` is unicode text (a sequence of unicode codepoints), like the 2.x `unicode` type. The default UTF8 in Python 3 refers to the *source file* encoding if you don't use an  [encoding declaration](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) (it was ASCII before Python 3 and iso 8859-1 pre-2.5).

Answer (score 0):

Unicode is an object type whereas 'u' is a literal used to denote that object is unicode object. It is similar to 'L' literal used to denote long int.

Comment: Except the `L` prefix isn't needed to create a long int if your literal is > `sys.maxint`, and `long(123)` doesn't make a translation step that can be regulated with an extra argument.

Comment: Moreover, for all but indexing operations and certain C calls, long integers and regular integers are all but the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:'上午'.decode('utf8','ignore').encode('utf8')

Comment: Would you like to elaborate a bit? Thank you.

Comment: I tried, this actually works when I read a file containing non-ascii code. So I upvote it.

Comment: Why the additional encode? Sure `'byte str literal'.decode('source codec')` will do the same thing as `unicode('byte str literal', 'source codec')`.

Comment: @DehengYe: that's because the `'ignore'` error handler will cause **any** input to work. It doesn't mean that you got usable text.

Comment: And why *'ignore'*? That just masks any problems, what if the input is not actually UTF-8?

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you so much for your dedication.

Comment: @DehengYe: Say your input file uses the [GBK codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK), then using `line.decode('utf8', 'ignore')` will give you a result, but it won't be any *useful* result. `u'上午'.encode('gbk').decode('utf8', 'ignore')` gives you an *empty string* as all the bytes in the encoded string are not valid UTF-8 bytes, so they all are ignored when decoding. But GBK is one of the most common codecs used for Chinese text.