# Problems with unicode, beautifulsoup, cld2, and python

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup, language-detection

I'm trying to detect the language of a number of pages in beautifulsoup/python.

This is how I use beautiful soup to generate the text object...

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
text=soup.findAll('body')[-1].text
```

This produces a unicode object, but I often get the following error when I run cld2 on it.

```
>>> cld2.detect(text)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 116: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If I encode it, I no longer get that error for that particular text.

```
>>> cld2.detect(text.encode('utf-8'))
(True, 4810, (('DUTCH', 'nl', 68, 845.0), ('ENGLISH', 'en', 31, 922.0), ('Unknown', 'un', 0, 0.0)))
```

...but I end up getting different errors for another piece of text

```
>>> cld2.detect(second_text)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1158-1161: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> cld2.detect(second_text.encode('utf-8'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cld2.error: input contains invalid UTF-8 around byte 2079 (of 2605)
```

All of this encoding stuff completely baffles me. Is there some way to ensure that I have only valid utf-8 and unicode characters?

Comment: Do you know the encoding of `content`?  See the `bs4` [documentation on this issue](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings).

Comment: Everything that I am grabbing is scraped from the web using Beautiful Soup. For that last item that had the "can't encode characters" error, the html specifies "charset='utf-8'"

Comment: For just that document, try passing `BeautifulSoup(content, from_encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work.

I am also scraping a very large number of documents, and I wouldn't be able to manually set the rules for each one. I would 100% be willing to strip out items that are perceived to be junk. I don't think these obscure characters will have a large impact on language detection, but I could be wrong.

Comment: To quote a famous podiatrist: there's no one-size-fits all in the wild. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32111908/1599229) and go from there.

Comment: *Encoding* into UTF-8 presumes that what you have is already Unicode.  That part is certainly wrong.