# Pyspark RDD: convert to string

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Using `rddfloat = rdd.map( (float(x[0]), float(x[1])) )`, I converted the columns of an rdd into floats so that I could do math with them. Now I'm finished with the math and I want to convert them back into their original StringType.

I've tried rddstr = rddfloat( (str(x[0]), str(x[1]), str(x[2])) ), and it does return a string `'40.745555'`, but that's not the same as the original rdd `u'40.745555'`. What is the difference between these, and how can I convert it back to how it was originally?

Comment: The original string is actually a unicode so if you will do `unicode(x[0])` you will get what you wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using Python 2.X. This means that if you want to produce a unicode string, you need to call unicode, like

```
rddstr = rddfloat( (unicode(x[0]), str(x[1]), str(x[2])) )
```

However, to have a better understanding of the differences, I would suggest you to search online, because it's a pretty common question. For example, some of the answers reported in the following questions might sound reasonable for you:

- [What is the difference between u' ' prefix and unicode() in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111835/what-is-the-difference-between-u-prefix-and-unicode-in-python)
- [Python str vs unicode types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034272/python-str-vs-unicode-types)

In particular, this answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18034409/126125