# Get JSON data (Django)

Tags: json, django

This my model

Driver Model

```
class Driver(models.Model):
    named = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    ident = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.named
```

manufacture model

```
class Carlcid(models.Model):
    namec = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lc_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.namec)
```

Car model

```
class Car(models.Model):
    f_idcar = models.ForeignKey(Carlcid, related_name='carlcd')
    id_driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.f_idcar)
```

This My views

```
def get_name_driver(request):
    name = request.GET.get('name')
    query = Car.objects.filter(f_idcar__namec=name)
    results=[]
    for q in query:
        m_json={}
        m_json['nama']= q.named
        results.append(m_json)
    return HttpResponse(results,"application/json")
```

i get `{'nama': <Driver: Michael>}`

but i wont get result like this `{'nama': "Michael"}`, How to get result like that, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must get the **driver** name with the following line :

```
m_json['nama']= q.id_driver.named
```

Your new view :

```
def get_name_driver(request):
    name = request.GET.get('name')
    query = Car.objects.filter(f_idcar__namec=name)
    results=[]
    for q in query:
        m_json={}
        m_json['nama']= q.id_driver.named
        results.append(m_json)
    return HttpResponse(results,"application/json")
```

In addition to my answer, I want give you an advice :

You should named your foreign key like the model. Yes, in database it will be store the driver id, but when you use Django ORM, you don't get the id of driver but a **Driver** object.

So I advise you to rename **id_driver** by **driver** so you will use

```
m_json['nama']= q.driver.named
```

but it's not required, just advise ;)

Comment: where `id_driver` come from?, my driver table has `id` , `named`, `ident`

Comment: Your **query** variable get records from **Car** model, so you get **Car** fields : **id_driver** and **f_idcar**

Comment: thanks but i get `u` in result `{'nama': u'Michael'}`, how to remove `u`

Comment: I'm not sure (I use only Python 3 from years) but you can try : 
**m_json['nama']= q.driver.named.decode('utf-8')**
or
**m_json['nama']= str(q.driver.named)**

Comment: If it helps you, you can read this for your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761361/suppress-the-uprefix-indicating-unicode-in-python-strings. Good luck, Django is a very fun framework :)