# how to get rid of unicode characters in python output?

Tags: python, json, unicode

i am trying to load a json file and then trying to parse it later.
however, in the output i keep getting the 'u' characters.
I tried to open the file with encoding='utf-8' which dint solve the problem.
i am using python 2.7. is there a straight forward approach or workaround to ignore and get ride of the 'u' characters in the output.

```
import json
import io


with io.open('/tmp/install-report.json', encoding='utf-8') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    print d
```

o/p

```
{u'install': {u'Status': u'In Progress...', u'StartedAt': 1471772544,}}
```

p.s: i went trough this post [Suppress the u'prefix indicating unicode' in python strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761361/suppress-the-uprefix-indicating-unicode-in-python-strings)
but that doesn't have a solution for python 2.7

Comment: In short: [**no**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761361/suppress-the-uprefix-indicating-unicode-in-python-strings).

Comment: Why is it  an issue?

Comment: Unicode is nothing to do with the problem. This is the Python (`repr()`) representation of a dictionary full of character strings. If you want a representation in another format such as JSON then use an encoder for that format.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that's an issue because this needs to be displayed to an end user who may not be comfortable with these 'characters'

Comment: @cool77 But you're already assuming the end user is comfortable with the python `repr` output? First of all, what kind of output do you expect? The time stamp doesn't look end-user friendly either.

Comment: @roeland i am expecting an output without the 'u' characters in the o/p. 
something like :
{'install': 'Status': 'In Progress...', 'StartedAt': 1471772544,}}

well, the time stamp issue i can handle by typecasting the object to string. that's not a prob

Answer (score 2):

Use json.dumps and decode it to convert it to string

```
data = json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False).decode('utf8')
print data
```

Comment: @cool77 Please mark the answer as Correct if it solved your problem

Comment: i tried the solution. it helps. but i need to use the dictionary 'd' from json.load later in the script. by using the json.dumps , i get a string with which i cannot later iterate as in a dictionary/

Comment: So keep both the `d` dictionary and the `data` string and use whichever one you need.

Answer (score 0):

`u` just indicates a Unicode string.  If you print the string, it won't be displayed:

```
d = {u'install': {u'Status': u'In Progress...', u'StartedAt': 1471772544}}

print 'Status:',d[u'install'][u'Status']
```

Output:

```
Status: In Progress...
```