# How to pretty print dictionaries in iPython

Tags: python, rethinkdb

I'm currently using RethinkDB, which has a nice web UI with a Data Explorer which allows the user to print out the contents of the database like this:

[image]

Note that each key-value pair starts on a new line, and the keys and values (mostly) have different colors. By contrast, if I print out the same using iPython, I get an almost illegible result:

[image]

This is slightly ameliorated if I iterate over the cursor and `print` each item, like so:

[image]

However, this requires more typing and still doesn't look as good as the RethinkDB web UI. Is there perhaps an iPython plugin that I can install to improve the appearance of the printed output?

(I had a look at [pprint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html), but this seems to control only the positioning of the text and not its color).

Comment: At your comment regarding PPrint: is indentation of pprint not sufficient? Removing the unicode of a string is also hard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761361/suppress-the-uprefix-indicating-unicode-in-python-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps):

```
import json 

for row in r.db(....).run(conn):
    print(json.dumps(row, indent=4))
```

Although this does not display the keys in sorted order, as appears to be the case in the example, it might be sufficient for your needs. As pointed out by @coder, you `json.dumps()` can sort the keys by specifying the `sort_keys=True` parameter.

```
for row in r.db(....).run(conn):
    print(json.dumps(row, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

It might also be possible to print the object directly (haven't tested this):

```
print(json.dumps(r.db(....).run(conn), indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

which might also print out the surrounding "list" object.

---

To handle objects that do not support serialisation to JSON you can use a custom [`JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder). Here is an example which handles `datetime.datetime` objects:

```
from datetime import datetime

class DateTimeAwareJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime):
            tz = obj.tzname()
            return obj.ctime() + (' {}'.format(tz) if tz else '')
        return super(DateTimeAwareJSONEncoder, self).default(obj)

for row in r.db(....).run(conn):
    print(json.dumps(row, indent=4, sort_keys=True, cls=DateTimeAwareJSONEncoder))
```

You can use [`datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to format the date time string as required.

Comment: if needed you can sort the keys using `json.dumps` with the parameter `sort_keys=True` ...

Comment: This does not work for dicts with non-JSON-serializable objects, e.g. `Decimal`.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson: so write a custom JSON encoder for `Decimal` as I've shown for `datetime` objects.

Answer (score 0):

[mhawke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21945/mhawke)'s answer works if one adds the keyword argument `time_format="raw"` to RethinkDB's `run()` command. (Otherwise, you get a `TypeError` because RethinkDB's object containing the time zone is not JSON serializable). The result looks like this:

[image]

which is much more legible. A slight drawback is that the `epoch_time` is more difficult to interpret than the original time format.

Comment: You can use a custom `JSONEncoder` to handle the `datetime` objects. See my updated answer.