# Python: How to get string from item without [u'']

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode

I'm using python 2.7 for this here. I've got a bit of code to extract certain mp3 tags, like this here

```
mp3info = EasyID3(fileName)
print mp3info
print mp3info['genre']
print mp3info.get('genre', default=None)
print str(mp3info['genre'])
print repr(mp3info['genre'])
genre = unicode(mp3info['genre'])
print genre
```

I have to use the name ['genre'] instead of [2] as the order can vary between tracks. It produces output like this

```
{'artist': [u'Really Cool Band'], 'title': [u'Really Cool Song'], 'genre': [u'Rock'], 'date': [u'2005']}
[u'Rock']
[u'Rock']
[u'Rock']
[u'Rock']
[u'Rock']
```

At first I was like, "Why thank you, I do rock" but then I got on with trying to debug the code. As you can see, I've tried a few different approaches, but none of them work. All I want is for it to output

```
Rock
```

I reckon I could possibly use split, but that could get very messy very quickly as there's a distinct possibility that artist or title could contain '

Any suggestions?

Comment: That u is just  something that prints out. It's not part of the string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761361/suppress-the-uprefix-indicating-unicode-in-python-strings

Answer (score 1):

It's not a string that you can use `split` on,, it's a list; that list usually (always?) contains one item. So you can get that first item:

```
genre = mp3info['genre'][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[u'Rock']
```

Is a *list* of length 1, its single element is a Unicode string.

Try

```
 print genre[0]
```

To only print the first element of the list.