# remove the prefix u' from the list

Tags: python, numpy

This could be easier one but this one is bugging me for a while. Help would be greatly appreciated.

**Problem Definition:** 
Make the list output looks good by removing the unicode value prefixed to the data.

Here is my code:

```
nfl = np.genfromtxt("drinks.csv", dtype="<U75", skip_header=1, delimiter=",")
print(nfl)
```

output is as follows:

```
[[u'Afghanistan' u'0' u'0' u'0' u'0.0']
 [u'Albania' u'89' u'132' u'54' u'4.9']
 [u'Algeria' u'25' u'0' u'14' u'0.7']
 [u'Andorra' u'245' u'138' u'312' u'12.4']
 [u'Angola' u'217' u'57' u'45' u'5.9']]
```

I also tried to print it like print(str(nfl)).No luck!How would I modify the output?

What I wanted to see is

```
[['Afghanistan' '0' '0' '0' '0.0']
 ['Albania' '89' '132' '54' '4.9']
 ['Algeria' '25' '0' '14' '0.7']
 ['Andorra' '245' '138' '312' '12.4']
 ['Angola' '217' '57' '45' '5.9']]
```

Comment: I'm not an expert, but can't you do this with regex?
Try:
u\'
and replace for '

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppress the u'prefix indicating unicode' in python strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761361/suppress-the-uprefix-indicating-unicode-in-python-strings)

Comment: Your dtype in loading specifies unicode `<U75`. Try `S75`, bytestrings (regular strings in py2).  Experiment with `dtype=None`, which should give numeric fields as well.  But pay attention to the resulting array shape and dtype.

Comment: thank you @hpaulj. S75 did the trick. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hpaulj comment helped  me and I got the desired output.

```
nfl = np.genfromtxt("drinks.csv", dtype="S75", skip_header=1, delimiter=",")
print(nfl)
```

I have got my desired output:

```
[['Afghanistan' '0' '0' '0' '0.0']
 ['Albania' '89' '132' '54' '4.9']
 ['Algeria' '25' '0' '14' '0.7']
 ['Andorra' '245' '138' '312' '12.4']
 ['Angola' '217' '57' '45' '5.9']]
```

Thanks All!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the encoding to utf8 (the u stands for Unicode).
Code example:

```
item.encode('utf8')
```

Remember to import the library 'unicodedata'.

Answer (score 0):

The commas are missing form your lists which won't help but I think it's just that you are seeing the list is its raw state.  If you actually pull out the data you'll find the 'u' is gone.

```
data = [[u'Afghanistan', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0.0'],
 [u'Albania', u'89', u'132', u'54', u'4.9'],
 [u'Algeria', u'25', u'0', u'14', u'0.7'],
 [u'Andorra', u'245', u'138', u'312', u'12.4'],
 [u'Angola', u'217', u'57', u'45', u'5.9']]

for country in data:
    for item in country:
        print item
```

I hope that's what you're asking.

Comment: The commas are missing because he is printing a numpy array, not a list of lists.