# Merge JSON to list

Tags: python, json

I have 2 json files! f1.json and f2.json

Contents: "f1.json"

```
{
  "tests":
    [
      {"a": "one", "b": "two"},
      {"a": "one", "b": "two"}
    ]
}
```

Contents: "f2.json"

```
{
  "tests":
    [
      {"c": "three", "d": "four"}
    ]
}
```

Required output - in list format

```
[{a:"one",b:"two"},{a:"one",b:"two"},{c:"three",d:"four"}]
```

I'm getting the same output in the "unicode" format. 
Does anyone have a way to get it without the unicode?

My output

```
[{u'a': u'one', u'b': u'two'}, {u'a': u'one', u'b': u'two'}, {u'c': u'three', u'd': u'four'}]
```

Code:

```
files=['t1.json','t2.json']      


import json,ast                          

empty = []                             


for elements in files:           
    fh = open(elements, 'r')             
    filedata = fh.read()                 
    fh.close()                           
    data = json.loads(filedata)          

    empty.append(data['tests'])        
final = []                            
for elements in empty:                 
    for dict in elements:                
        final.append(dict)            
print final
```

Comment: I made an edit with more details. Please take a look

Comment: you're printing a python list, so your output is in python list format. If you want your output in JSON format, you should probably convert your data to JSON before printing: `print json.dumps(final)`

Comment: same output! no change

Comment: I very much doubt that. But another good solution would be to upgrade to python3

Comment: I dont want the output to be string! it has to be in the dict format. Doing what you suggested does solve the issue but creates an ever bigger issue for me

Comment: It is in the dict format. The unicode markers are valid python

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761361/suppress-the-uprefix-indicating-unicode-in-python-strings

Comment: Not clear what's wrong with the data. It's a dictionary. You can access it fine

Answer (score 0):

You could get string object instead of Unicode ones from JSON.

Refer to [Mark Amery's function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13105359/1709587) and [How to get string objects instead of Unicode ones from JSON in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956867/how-to-get-string-objects-instead-of-unicode-ones-from-json-in-python/13105359#13105359)

So you can convert the Unicode `data`(variable) to `string object` in your code after the line:

```
data = json.loads(filedata)
data = byteify(data)    # Add this line according to Mark Amery's function
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
import json

l = []
files=['t1.json','t2.json']
for file in files:
   with open(file, 'r') as file:
       d = json.loads(file.read())
       l.extend(d["tests"])
print l
```