# Python Structlog - hide u'' from unicode strings

Tags: python, unicode

I have a Python2 application which logs via the structlog library, and downstream the logs are captured an extracted using key/value syntax. However, the extraction isn't working when unicode strings are involved - the u is being prepended to unicode strings, breaking the parser.

Is it possible to configure the KeyValueRenderer to exclude the u''?

```
import structlog
structlog.configure(processors=[structlog.processors.KeyValueRenderer()])
l = structlog.get_logger()
l.error('I am ASCII')
l.error(u'I am Unicode')
```

Result:

```
event='I am ASCII'
event=u'I am Unicode'
```

Desired:

```
event='I am ASCII'
event='I am Unicode'
```

I know there are questions to change Python's global printing behavior for Unicode strings - but I'm just looking to change the behavior in structlog's approach to printing them.

Comment: How do you want strings with non-ASCII characters to appear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppress the u'prefix indicating unicode' in python strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761361/suppress-the-uprefix-indicating-unicode-in-python-strings)

Comment: It seems likely that doing this will just break the parser differently, because it'll reconstruct the wrong string. You may want to consider instead enhancing the parser.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams in this case, the strings are all ASCII but the API we're getting them from defaults everything to unicode strings. to user2357112 I don't see how removing the u before the string is printed will cause us issues - since we're correctly parsing quoted strings without the u'' now.

Comment: `u'\u1000'` represents a very different string from `'\u1000'` (in Python 2 notation).

Comment: @mangoHero1 the difference here is that I'm looking specifically for a change to structlog's logging - I'm not looking for a global change to the unicode printing behavior. I've tried pulling levers like repr_native_str=True but that didn't get at what I needed

Comment: The docs for [KeyValueRenderer](https://structlog.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#structlog.processors.KeyValueRenderer) show there is an argument for this: `repr_native_str=False`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [structlog.processors.UnicodeEncoder](https://structlog.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#structlog.processors.UnicodeEncoder) is for.  It takes unicode strings and encodes them to byte strings.

Once you use Python 3, you want [structlog.processors.UnicodeDecoder](https://structlog.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#structlog.processors.UnicodeDecoder) to prevent `b` prefixes.