# Table Scraping with same class attributes

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the prayer time from a website which is www.hujjat.org.

Here is the html part of the area I am interested in (as you may have noticed the class attribute is the same for all the 4 prayers):

```
<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="NamaazTimes">
                <div class="NamaazTimeName">Fajr</div>
                <div class="NamaazTime">04:42</div>
            </td>
            <td class="NamaazTimes">
                <div class="NamaazTimeName">Sunrise</div>
                <div class="NamaazTime">06:32</div>
            </td>
            <td class="NamaazTimes">
                <div class="NamaazTimeName">Zohr</div>
                <div class="NamaazTime">13:02</div>
            </td>
            <td class="NamaazTimes">
                <div class="NamaazTimeName">Maghrib</div>
                <div class="NamaazTime">19:33</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So far I have written the following code:

```
# import libraries
import json
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# specify the url
quote_page = 'http://www.hujjat.org/'
# query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
# parse the html using beautiful soap and store in variable 'soup'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find("div",class_="NamaazTimeName", text="Fajr").find_previous("table")
for row in table.find_all("tr"):
    a = row.find_all("td")

   # print(row.find_all("td"))

print (a)
```

And my result is :

```
[<td class="NamaazTimes">\n<div class="NamaazTimeName">Fajr</div>\n<div class="NamaazTime">04:42</div>\n</td>, <td class="NamaazTimes">\n<div class="NamaazTimeName">Sunrise</div>\n<div class="NamaazTime">06:32</div>\n</td>, <td class="NamaazTimes">\n<div class="NamaazTimeName">Zohr</div>\n<div class="NamaazTime">13:02</div>\n</td>, <td class="NamaazTimes">\n<div class="NamaazTimeName">Maghrib</div>\n<div class="NamaazTime">19:33</div>\n</td>]
```

What I want from my code is just the time for each of the prayer e.g. If it is "Fajr" prayer then the output should be "04:42". I then want to save this "04:42" in a text file.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.hujjat.org/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
path = 'C:/Users/John/Documents/Python/'

namaazNames = soup.select('div.NamaazTimeName')
namaazNames = [namaazName.text for namaazName in namaazNames]
namaazTimes = soup.select('div.NamaazTime')
namaazTimes = [namaazTime.text for namaazTime in namaazTimes]
del namaazNames[1]
del namaazTimes[1]

for namaazName, namaazTime in zip(namaazNames, namaazTimes):
    with open(path + namaazName + '.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(namaazTime)
```

Comment: Thanks @jxpython. It does work however I forgot to mention in my question that I want to save one particular time in my text file. So for example just **04:44**. How can I do that? I am not too familiar with slice in python. Thanks

Comment: So you only need 04:42 in your text file?

Comment: Thank you @jxpython. So what are the text files called? I put a text file name and it throws this error:

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test4.py", line 18, in <module>
    with open(a + '/home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/python_scripts/test3.txt', 'w') as file:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'Fajr/home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/python_scripts/test3.txt'`

Comment: The names of the text files are the prayer names. So Fajr, Sunrise, Zohr and Maghrib.

Comment: I seems like the directory you are giving doesn't exist.

Comment: No just leave the code as it is. The four text files will be saved in the same directory as the Python file.

Comment: Well thanks a lot for your help @jxpython I see that now.

Comment: God Bless you I definitely will !

Comment: sorry to bother you again on this. Just for my future reference, if I wanted to change the location of all the 4 text files where they are saved. How do I do that? thanks

Comment: Change the path variable to the full directory path you want to save the text files. Line 7.

Comment: That did not work I am afraid. I specified the path in line 7 but I cannot see any .txt file being saved in that folder.

Comment: You didn't forget the last "/" at the end of the path? If you didn't, show me the path you used.

Comment: You are correct I forgot the last "/" Thank you very much.

Comment: ok I have sorted my previous query I just wanted to ask you as you have used the for loop in the code I only wanted 3 prayer times and not the sunrise time. So I basically I need the output to delete or not show the 2nd row which is the sunrise time. I used sys.stdout.write(ERASE_LINE) but I cannot explicitly specify the 2nd row. Any help will be appreciated as usual. Thanks

Comment: I have made an attempt but it produces "not working" even when the actual time matches the prayer time.

I have put my code above

thanks.

Comment: So you want to exclude Sunrise? Only include the other three prayer times and make a txt file?

Comment: Well yeah yes but I cannot post my code here if you could please see this question I asked and my code maybe it will make better sense. Thanks.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536372/match-two-values-and-result-an-output

Comment: so what does your code do now? just print 3 times and not sunrise?

Comment: Make txt files with each prayer time. Sunrise not. So only Fajr, Zohr and Maghrib

Comment: right ok thanks for that. 

I now want to match each prayer time to the current time and play an mp3 file. I have attempted it but it does not execute. Can you please look into this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536372/match-two-values-and-result-an-output ? 

thanks

Comment: Let me check in a moment

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use **select** instead of find in order to make a query more similar to a browser's css selectors. This way you could just get all the inner texts in the same list and work from there.

Something similar to this should help:

```
# import libraries
import json
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# specify the url
quote_page = 'http://www.hujjat.org/'
# query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
# parse the html using beautiful soap and store in variable 'soup'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find("div",class_="NamaazTimeName", text="Fajr").find_previous("table")
texts = [x.text for x in table.select("td.NamaazTimes div")]
only_times = [texts[x+1] for x in range(0, len(texts), 2)]

# we'll open the file in a with block, so we don't need to close it
with open("foo.txt", "w") as fp:
    # you'll need to iterate each string
    for row in only_times:
        fp.write(row + "\n")
```

EDIT(2): Re-phrased my comments in the code
EDIT(3): Did some sode cleanup and changed to only store the times.

Comment: Hi Pedro Thank you for your answer. I tried your code and I get the following: [(u'Fajr', u'04:42'), (u'Sunrise', u'06:32'), (u'Zohr', u'13:02'), (u'Maghrib', u'19:33')]
 I was wondering if I could change and only get e.g. Fajr 04:42? Is that possible?

Comment: Are you referring to the concatenation of the two fields? Or the 'u' suffix? In case you are referring to the u suffix, it means that your strings are in unicode instead of ascii. I am not sure if you can "turn it off". But it shouldn't show up when you save it to the file. You can always encode them as ascii, but you might need to make some decisions...

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207479/5409287), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/761459/5409287) or [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: Hi Pedro so I added the following lines to save it to a text file:

Comment: fo = open('/home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/python_scripts/test3.txt', 'w')
fo.write(times_pairs)
fo.close()

Comment: But I get this error now: [(u'Fajr', u'04:44'), (u'Sunrise', u'06:34'), (u'Zohr', u'13:02'), (u'Maghrib', u'19:31')]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 27, in <module>
    fo.write(times_pairs)
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object

Comment: Hi Pedro....thank you for the answer. I have tried to iterate each string using this method:

Comment: str2 = "Fajr"
startnum = int(times_pairs_str.index(str2))
newname = times_pairs_str[startnum + 5 :startnum + 10]
print (newname)

with open("/home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/python_scripts/test3.txt", "w") as fp:
    # you'll need to iterate each string
    for row in times_pairs_str:
        fp.write(row + "\n")

Comment: but I get an error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 32, in <module>
    startnum = int(times_pairs_str.index(str2))
ValueError: 'Fajr' is not in list

Comment: Wait, maybe my phrasing in the code's comments was a bit misleading. The code as is should work. You'll need to change "foo.txt" with your path to your file.

Comment: I have done that and in my test3.text file the data save is as a list with 4 lines i.e.

Comment: `Fajr 04:44`
`Sunrise 06:34`
`Zohr 13:02`
`Maghrib 19:31`

Comment: I wanted just the time so when I save my results in my test3.txt, the test3.txt file should only contain **ONE** time like this **`04:44`** and nothing else. `find()` doesnt work with lists I tried it.

Comment: Pedro is it possible to show only one time? only one like **04:44**??

Comment: I see from your other comments that you would like the times in different files. How should the files be named? Numerically? Or using one of the fields? Maybe you could update your question to also have this information.

Answer (score 0):

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd

    data = BeautifulSoup(#HTML data)

    NamaazName = data.find_all('div', {'class':'NamaazTimeName'})
    NamaazTime = data.find_all('div', {'class':'NamaazTime'})

    for i in range(len(NamaazName)):
        coll[NamaazName[i].text] = NamaazTime[i].text

    master_data.columns=pd.DataFrame()

    master_data['NamaazName'] = coll.keys()
    master_data['NamaazTime'] = coll.values()

   print(master_data)
```

Output

```
    Nammaz  NammazTime
0    Fajr     04:42 
1    Sunrise  06:32 
2    Zohr     13:02 
3    Maghrib  19:33
```

Comment: Hi Sarthank I tried your code but I dont think its complete. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: could you tell where you are facing the problem because according to the raw html given in your problem above code works..

Comment: Basically is there anything I need to add to your code? As I copied it but throws errors

Comment: whats the error ?.. also the code is based on the raw html which you pasted above..you will have to make changes accordingly

Comment: I get the error:   File "test3.py", line 15
    NamaazTime = data.find_all('div', {'class':'NamaazTime'})
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: there is no syntax error in that line...make sure data is your soup object..do one thing take your raw html which you pasted above, insert in a variable then pass it through soup (#HTML PART)...then run the above code you will see..o