# Formatting JSON output in Python

Tags: python, json

How do I format my JSON output so that it looks human readable and I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
"user1":{
    "Country":[
        "China", "USA", "Nepal"
    ],
     "Name": [
        "Lisbon"
    ]
},

"user2":{
    "Country":[
        "Sweden", "China", "USA"
    ],
     "Name": [
        "Jade"
    ]
},

"user3":{
    "Country":[
        "India", "China", "USA"
    ],
     "Name": [
        "John"
    ]
}
```

Here's my code:

```
user = raw_input("Enter user's name: ")
with open('Users.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for k, v in data.items():
    if any(x in data[user]['Country'] for x in v['Country']):
        print(v['Name'])
```

So far my output looks like this:

```
[u'Lisbon']
[u'Jade']
[u'John']
```

I would like an output that looks like this, how do I go around that?:

```
Lisbon
Jade
John
```

Comment: `print(v['Name'][0])` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppress the u'prefix indicating unicode' in python strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761361/suppress-the-uprefix-indicating-unicode-in-python-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change `print(v['Name'])` for `print(v['Name'][0])`

Answer (score 0):

The `u` in `u'Jade'` signifies that the string is [encoded in Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761361/suppress-the-uprefix-indicating-unicode-in-python-strings). You can use `print(unicode(v['Name'][0]))` if you wish to print the bare string, but it makes no difference in the underlying data type.

You probably want to check out [pretty-printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-prettyprint-a-json-file) JSON if you will continue working on with JSON objects in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the various answers people! But I managed to find figure it out on my own, I tweaked my print statement into this!

```
userName = raw_input("Enter user's name: ")
with open('extracted_data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for k, v in data.items():
    if any(x in data[userName]['Acceptable_country'] for x in v['Acceptable_country']):
        print(", ".join(v['Name']))
```