# Unicode Support in Various Programming Languages

Tags: unicode, programming-languages

I'd like to have a canonical place to pool information about Unicode support in various languages. Is it a part of the core language? Is it provided in libraries? Is it not available at all? Is there a resource popular resource for Unicode information in a language? One language per answer please. Also if you could make the language a heading that would make it easier to find.

Comment: How should the votes be interpreted when the answers don't really compete with each other (because of just one answer per language)? "Usefulness of the answer", as usual, or perhaps "Overall quality of Unicode support in that language"? :)

Comment: Not really sure. I've been up voting them when I thought they provided some useful information.

Comment: I made it CW because I want people to improve and expand the answer. My hope is that when I want to find out out unicode support in language X, I can come here and find some useful information.

Comment: CW is definitely the right thing here. There are many “right” answers, one for each language that has something to say on the topic. (Not that I'm sure what good criteria for voting an answer up are.)

Answer (score 12):

## Perl

Perl has built-in Unicode support, mostly. Sort of. From perldoc:

- [perlunitut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html) - Tutorial on using Unicode in Perl. Largely teaches in absolute terms about what you should and should not do as far as Unicode. Covers basics.
- [perlunifaq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html) - Frequently asked questions about Unicode in Perl.
- [perluniintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro.html) - Introduction to Unicode in Perl. Less "preachy" than [perlunitut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html).
- [perlunicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html) - For when you absolutely have to know everything there is to know about Unicode and Perl.

Comment: Great answer! This is _exactly_ the sort of thing I was hoping to get.

Comment: I've distilled most of that information into the Unicode chapter in _Effective Perl Programming_. Making sense of the spread out docs was not that fun.

Answer (score 10):

### Python 3k

Python 3k (or 3.0 or 3000) has new approach for handling text (unicode) and data:
[Text Vs. Data Instead Of Unicode Vs. 8-bit](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit). See also [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/unicode.html).

Answer (score 8):

## Java

Same as with .NET, Java uses UTF-16 internally: [java.lang.String](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

> A `String` represents a string in the UTF-16 format in which *supplementary characters* are represented by *surrogate pairs* (see the section [Unicode Character Representations](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode) in the `Character` class for more information). Index values refer to `char` code units, so a supplementary character uses two positions in a `String`.

Answer (score 7):

## HQ9+

The Q command has complete Unicode support in most implementations.

Answer (score 6):

## **Go**

Google's [Go programming language](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Source_code_representation) supports Unicode and works with UTF-8.

Answer (score 6):

### Rust

Rust's strings (`std::String` and `&str`) are always valid UTF-8, and do not use null terminators, and as a result can not be indexed as an array, like they can be in C/C++, etc. They can be sliced somewhat like Go using `.get` since 1.20, with the caveat that it will fail if you try slicing the middle of a code point.

Rust also has `OsStr`/`OsString` for interacting with the Host OS. It's byte array on Unix (containing any sequence of bytes). On windows it's WTF-8 (A super-set of UTF-8 that handles the improperly formed Unicode strings that are allowed in Windows and Javascript), `&str` and `String` can be freely converted to `OsStr` or `OsString`, but require checks to covert the other way. Either by Failing on invalid unicode, or replacing with the Unicode replacement char. (There is also `Path`/`PathBuf`, which are just wrappers around `OsStr`/`OsString`).

There is also the `CStr` and `CString` types, which represent Null terminated C strings, like `OsStr` on Unix they can contain arbitrary bytes.

Rust doesn't directly support UTF-16. But can convert `OsStr` to UCS-2 on windows.

Answer (score 5):

## Python

Python 2 has the classes `str` and `unicode`. `str` objects store bytes, `unicode` objects store UTF-16 characters. Most library functions support both (e.g. `os.listdir('.')` returns a list of `str`, `os.listdir(u'.')` returns a list of `unicode` objects). Both have `encode` and `decode` methods.

Python 3 basically renamed `unicode` to `str`. The Python 3 equivalent to `str` would be the type `bytes`. `bytes` has a `decode` and `str` an `encode` method. [Since Python 3.3](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/) `str` objects internally use one of several encodings in order to save memory. For a Python programmer it still looks like an abstract unicode sequence.

Python supports:

- encoding/decoding
- normalization
- simple case conversion and splitting on whitespace
- looking up characters by their name

Python does not support/has limited support for:

- collation (limited)
- special case conversions where there is no 1:1 mapping between lower and upper case characters
- regular expressions ([it's worked on](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex))
- text segmentation
- bidirectional text handling

See also: [The Truth about Unicode in Python](http://www.cmlenz.net/archives/2008/07/the-truth-about-unicode-in-python)

Comment: A summary and a mention of the Python version would be good (the article is old-ish and probably doesn't handle Python 3).

Comment: I'm getting "500 Internal Server Error" on that link.

Answer (score 4):

## Delphi

Delphi 2009 fully supports Unicode. They've changed the implementation of `string` to default to 16-bit Unicode encoding, and most libraries including the third party ones support Unicode. See Marco Cantù's [Delphi and Unicode](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38980).

Prior to Delphi 2009, the support for Unicode was limited, but there was `WideChar` and `WideString` to store the 16-bit encoded string. See [Unicode in Delphi](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Unicode_in_Delphi) for more info.

Note, you can still develop bilingual CJKV application without using Unicode. For example, [Shift JIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift%2DJIS) encoded string for Japanese can be stored using plain `AnsiString`.

Answer (score 3):

## .NET (C#, VB.NET, ...)

.NET stores [strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) internally as a sequence of [`System.Char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx) objects. One `System.Char` represents a UTF-16 [code unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_unit).

From the MSDN documentation on `System.Char`:

> The .NET Framework uses the **Char**
>   structure to represent a Unicode
>   character. The Unicode Standard
>   identifies each Unicode character with
>   a unique 21-bit scalar number called a
>   code point, and defines the UTF-16
>   encoding form that specifies how a
>   code point is encoded into a sequence
>   of one or more 16-bit values. Each
>   16-bit value ranges from hexadecimal
>   0x0000 through 0xFFFF and is stored in
>   a **Char** structure.

Additional resources:

- [Strings in .NET and C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html) (by Jon Skeet).

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript

Looks like before JS 1.3 there was no support for Unicode. As of 1.5, UTF-8, UTF-16 and UCS-2 are all supported. You can use Unicode escape sequences in strings, regexs and identifiers.
[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Unicode)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, most browser implementations still seem to be stuck in the dark ages of UCS-2.

Answer (score 3):

## Tcl

Tcl strings have been sequences of Unicode characters since [Tcl 8.1](http://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/i18n.html) (1999). Internally, they are morphed dynamically between UTF-8 (strictly [the same Modified UTF-8 as Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8) due to the handling of `U+00000` characters) and UCS-2 (in host endianness and BOM, of course). All external strings (with one exception), including those used to communicate with the OS, are internally Unicode before being transformed into whatever encoding is required for the host (or is manually configured on a communications channel). The exception is for where data is [copied between two communications channels](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/fcopy.htm) with a common encoding (and a few other restrictions not germane here) where a direct copy-free binary transfer is used.

Characters outside the BMP are not currently handled either internally or externally. This is a known issue.

Answer (score 3):

**R6RS Scheme**

Requires the implementation of Unicode 5.1. All strings are in 'unicode format'.

Answer (score 2):

## C/C++

### C

C before C99 has no built in unicode support. It uses zero terminated character arrays (`char*` or `char[]`) as strings. A `char` is specified to by a byte (8 bits).

C99 specifies `wcs`-functions in additions to the old `str`-functions (e.g. `strlen` -> `wcslen`). These functions take `wchar_t*` instead of `char*`. `wchar_t` stands for wide character type. The size of `wchar_t` is compiler-specific and can be as small as 8 bits. While different compilers indeed use different sizes, it's usually 16-bit (UTF-16) or 32-bit (UTF-32).

Most C library functions are transparent to UTF-8. E.g. if your operating system supports UTF-8 (and UTF-8 is configured as your systems charset), then creating a file using `fopen` passing an UTF-8 encoded string will create a properly named file.

### C++

The situation in C++ is very similar (`std::string` -> `std::wstring`), but there are at least efforts to get some sort of [unicode support in the standard library](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3572.html).

Comment: It should be noted that text stored in a wchar_t doesn't magically become Unicode - but any decent C programmer should know that nothing magically works in C. :)

Comment: It's equally accurate to say that C and C++ support Unicode via `char*` strings encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: UTF-8 is said to be more useful encoding for use in C++. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049947/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful
And it is natively supported via char*

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp (SBCL and CLisp)

According to [this](http://nolan.eakins.net/UnicodeAndLisp), [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/) and [CLisp](http://clisp.cons.org/) support Unicode.

Answer (score 2):

## Objective-C

None built-in, aside from whatever happens to be available as part of the C string library.

However, once you add frameworks…

## Foundation (Cocoa and Cocoa Touch) and Core Foundation

NSString and CFString each implement a fully Unicode-based string class (actually several classes, as an implementation detail). The two are “toll-free-bridged” so that the API for one can be used with instances of the other, and vice versa.

For data that doesn't necessarily represent text, there's NSData and CFData. NSString provides methods and CFString provides functions to encode text into data and decode text from data. Core Foundation supports more than a hundred different encodings, including all forms of the UTFs. The encodings are divided into two groups: [built-in encodings](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CFStringBuiltInEncodings), which are supported everywhere, and [external encodings](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/External_String_Encodings), which are at least supported on Mac OS X.

NSString provides methods for normalizing to forms D, KD, C, or KC. Each returns a new string.

Both NSString and CFString provide a wide variety of comparison/collation options. Here are [Foundation's comparison-option flags](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Search_and_Comparison_Options) and [Core Foundation's comparison-option flags](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/String_Comparison_Flags). They are not all synonymous; for example, Core Foundation makes literal (strict code-point-based) comparison the default, whereas Foundation makes non-literal comparison (allowing characters with accents to compare equal) the default.

Note that Core Foundation does not require Objective-C; indeed, it was created pretty much to provide most of the features of Foundation to Carbon programmers, who used straight C or C++. However, I suspect most modern usage of it is in Cocoa or Cocoa Touch programs, which are all written in Objective-C or Objective-C++.

Answer (score 2):

### D

D supports UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32 (char, wchar, and dchar, respectively). The table with all the types can be found [here](http://dlang.org/spec/type.html).

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby

The only stuff I can find for Ruby is pretty old and not being much of a rubist, I'm not sure how accurate it is.

> For the record, Ruby does support utf8, but not multibyte. Internally, it usually assumes strings are byte vectors, though there are libraries and tricks you can usually use to make things work.

Found that [here](http://blog.headius.com/2006/06/unicode-in-ruby-unicode-in-jruby.html).

### Ruby 1.9

Ruby 1.9 attaches encodings to strings. Binary strings use the encoding "ASCII-8BIT". While the default encoding is usually UTF-8 on any modern system, you cannot assume that all third party library functions always returns strings in this encoding. It might return any other encoding (e.g. some yaml parsers do that in some situations). If you concatenate two strings of different encoding you *might* get an `Encoding::CompatibilityError`.

Comment: Ruby has some bugs that make using unicode a pain for many use cases: http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/2034

Comment: I think the way Ruby handles encodings is idiotic. IMO strings and byte arrays should be two different things. Strings should not have any encoding associated with them, they should be abstract unicode code point sequences. You should get them via decoding byte arrays and you should get a byte array from a string via encoding it. This is what most (all?) other modern languages do.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP

There is already an [entire thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571694/what-factors-make-php-unicode-incompatible) on this on SO!

Answer (score 0):

## [Arc](http://www.paulgraham.com/arc.html)

Arc doesn't have any unicode support. [Yet](http://arclanguage.org/item?id=391).

Comment: I'd "-1" the article (not the answer!) based on the fact that the author equates "Unicode support" to "the color of the bicycle shed".

Answer (score 0):

### Lua

Lua 5.3 has a built-in `utf8` library, which handles the UTF-8 encoding. It allows you to convert a series of codepoints to the corresponding byte sequence and the other way around, get the length (the number of codepoints in a string), iterate over the codepoints in a string, get the byte position of the *n*th codepoint. It also provides a pattern, to be used by the pattern-matching functions in the `string` library, that will match one UTF-8 byte sequence.

Lua 5.3 has Unicode code point escape sequences that can be used in string literals (for instance, `"\u{61}"` for `"a"`). They translate to UTF-8 byte sequences.

Lua source code can be encoded in UTF-8 or any encoding in which ASCII characters take up one byte. UTF-16 and UTF-32 are not understood by the vanilla Lua interpreter. But strings can contain any encoding, or arbitrary binary data.