# Danish Æ being recognized as 2 letters instead of one

Tags: php

I've a simple code like so:

`echo strlen('Grækenland');`

and it's returning 11 instead of expected 10

The server is in denmark, locale was set to danish, but it still returns 11...

Comment: Does mb_strlen() give you 10?

Comment: Try `echo mb_strlen('Grækenland', 'UTF-8');`

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571694/what-factors-make-php-unicode-incompatible , https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-unicode/index.html and http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strlen` is one of the naïve PHP core functions that understand strings as byte arrays and assume one byte == one character. Use [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/mb_strlen) with the correct encoding parameter to actually count characters according to the encoding of your string.

Comment: I'll make an educated guess that UTF-8 is the correct encoding in this case because `æ` is 2 bytes and the other characters are 1 byte long in that encoding, which gives `11`.

Comment: Thanks for an explanation, that's much more helpful (as in I won't rely on strlen that much and/or use the correct function instead).

Comment: @user Indeed you do. See my profile for apropos articles if you want to know more about the topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  echo mb_strlen('Grækenland', 'utf8');
?>
```