# Convert "Java source code characters" in JSON string using PHP

Tags: php, json, encoding

I have a JSON string that contains `Dal\u00e9`. When I use `json_decode` on the JSON, it is converted to `DalÃ©`, however the original string that the JSON is from is `Dalé`. Why is this not converted properly?

I have [found](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm) that `"\u00E9"` is the C/C++/Java source code encoding for `é`. However, to me this doesn't answer why this is going wrong.

---

Example of incorrect PHP output:

```
<?php
$opts = array('http'=>array('ignore_errors' => true));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$jsonurl = "http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/552804.json";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl, false, $context);
$json_output = array(json_decode($json));
$json_error = $json_output[0]->error;
$json_message = $json_error->message;

foreach ($json_output[0]->{'loans'} as $loan) {
echo 'Name: '.$loan->{'name'};
}
?>
```

Comment: Because [PHP hates Unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/571694/20862).

Comment: php handles unicode escape sequences in json perfectly fine. Likely, you have borked the string somewhere else, or you haven't told the web browser that you're giving it utf8.

Comment: http://ideone.com/0BRsYA - it works fine

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: you're overdramatizing

Comment: Perhaps. But that doesn't necessarily mean that I'm wrong.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: well, sort of. "because" - is wrong. OP doesn't get correct result not because of php's issue, but his one (presumably with browser charset setting)

Comment: @zerkms it works fine with two \\ but notice that there is only one \ in the source JSON that I am retrieving.

Comment: @michaellindahl: two backslashes is a part of php string escaping syntax. If you `echo` it you would see there is only one backslash. (http://ideone.com/uNYDDq)

Comment: It would be convenient if all this character set nonsense could be handled internally. Unfortunately it's left to the coder to get wrong.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: it's a representation issue, not handling. You could blame browsers they support multiple charsets then.

Comment: @zerkms Can you get it to correctly parse this source: http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/552804.json

Comment: @michaellindahl: `$f = file_get_contents('http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/552804.json');

var_dump(json_decode($f));` --- it works fine. Make sure your browser's encoding is UTF-8, not something else.

Comment: @chris I can't change the source: http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/552804.json I'm using the following: `$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl, false, $context);
$json_output = array(json_decode($json));`

Comment: @zerkms it doesn't work fine for me. My browser is set to UTF-8, and I don't have access to everyone's browser anyways. Is there a way to correct the example code I just posted?

Comment: Is the server sending the page with the correct charset (utf8)?

Comment: @michaellindahl The browser, or your document?

Comment: @MarceloPascual No, apparently it wasn't

Comment: @Daedalus I thought I was asked to check the browser's encoding, which was UTF-8, however the document needed to have it's charset set through the PHP header (see accepted answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the web browser what encoding you are giving it.

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
var_dump(json_decode($jsonStr));
```

Comment: Note: for my case (having this inside a webpage) I will be using `header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: @michaellindahl: your comments are confusing ;-)

Comment: @zerkms they make complete sense to me :P apparently I wasn't setting the charset and relying on the default which was wrong. I didn't understand this needed to be set in the PHP header, which I've never had to do before.

Comment: Any reason why this needs to be done? Should I be setting the header in the PHP for every webpage or just in certain circumstances?

Comment: @michaellindahl: yep, it's a good idea to always set it explicitly, because sometimes browsers aren't good in guessing

Comment: @michaellindahl otherwise, a browser has to guess. And, there's many situations where it's not possible to guarantee a correct guess, which leads to erratic and baffling bugs throughout your software. A robust piece of web software always specifies the encoding, for every page, every time.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using php 5.4 you may use the function options of json_encode() like this :-

```
echo $b=json_encode('Dalé',JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo json_decode($b);
```